# Terminate a process after timeout using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to check if the process has been running from long time (say 5 minutes) and terminate if that's the case.

Below is the script I have written but it throws invalid property/method error:

```
Const MAX_TIME = 300 'seconds
const I = 1
arrTargetProcs = Array("example.exe")
'process names without extension
do while I = 1
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer)

For Each strTargetProc In arrTargetProcs
  Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process WHERE Name = '" & _
    strTargetProc & "'")
  If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
    For Each objProcess In colProcesses
      intProcDur = (objProcess.Timestamp_Object - _
       objProcess.ElapsedTime) / objProcess.Frequency_Object
      If Int(intProcDur) > MAX_TIME Then
        'WScript.Echo "Process " & objProcess.Name & " " & _
         'objProcess.IDProcess & " over time limit."
        Set objProc = objWMIService.Get _
         ("Win32_Process.Handle='" & objProcess.IDProcess & "'")
        intReturn = objProc.Terminate()
        If intReturn = 0 Then
          'WScript.Echo "  Process terminated."
        Else
          'WScript.Echo "  Unable to terminate process."
        End If
      Else
        'WScript.Echo "Process " & objProcess.Name & " " & _
        'objProcess.IDProcess & " not over time limit."
      End If
    Next
  Else
    'WScript.Echo "Process " & strTargetProc & " not found."
  End If
Next
WScript.Sleep 50000
Loop
```

I'm getting below error:

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objProcess.Timestamp_Object'

Is there way I can identify if the process has been running from 5 mins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `objProcess.CreationDate` value and compare against `Now` with a `DateDiff` call, and where the number of seconds > 300, call the `Terminate` method?

EDIT: Apologies, thought you were referencing the `Win32_Process` object.  For `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` the relevant property you want is `ElapsedTime`, which according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394323(v=vs.85).aspx) gives the number of seconds a process has been running.  Where this value is over 300, the process has been running for 5 mins or more.

`intProcDur = objProcess.ElapsedTime` should set intProcDur to the relevant value for your comparison

EDIT 2: The following modified version of your code retrieves the seconds since a process was started (in my case `vbsedit.exe`):

```
arrTargetProcs = Array("Vbsedit.exe")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer)

For Each strTargetProc In arrTargetProcs
    Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & strTargetProc & "'")
    If colProcesses.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objProcess In colProcesses
            intProcDur = objProcess.CreationDate
            intProcDur = CDate(Mid(intProcDur, 7,2) & "/" & Mid(intProcDur, 5, 2) & "/" & Left(intProcDur,4) & " " & Mid(intProcDur,9,2) & ":" & Mid(intProcDur, 11,2) & ":" & Mid(intProcDur,13,2))

            WScript.Echo objProcess.Name & ": " & intProcDur
            WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", intProcDur, Now) & " seconds since this process began."
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I can change it to Win32_Process object. I don't really understand the difference between them though. Can you please explain, how do I compare creation date and Now()? and get result in Seconds? DateDiff("S", Date1, Date2) is returning invalid datatype.

Comment: See additional EDIT 2